# On localhost, simple Google Analytic code only works in FireFox, not IE or Chrome- undefined exception in ga.js

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

Edited title to indicate i was working locally.

This was part of a larger project  but i have simplified to the following.

My google trackin code fires only in FireFox 28.0.
The same code does not fire in IE or in Chrome.

Using Fiddler, I can confirm that GA.js is being downloaded.
I then click on the Link.
In Firefox 28.0, i see a tracking request go out.
In IE and Chrome, nothing happens. There are no errors in the Console.
The code does break into ga.js and i get an exception (undefined). See call stack below code.

Am i doing something obviously wrong in the code below?
I have simplified it down to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>
    Home Page
</title><link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="default.aspx" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwMDUyNjYzMjhkZP9z+uGsx6oopXVpIrMvCo49qhSdX9KtN6fgRHcEez6N" />
</div>  
      <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Login', 'Button Click', 'Main Link Click']);" href="#">Go To My Site</a>
    </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement("script");
        ga.type = "text/javascript";
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s)
    })();
</script>
</html>
```

FWIW, in Chrome Developer tools, if i check the "Pause on Uncaught Exceptions", it stops at the following location in the minified ga.js code:
The exception is: *Paused on exception undefined*
  The call stack is as follows:

```
 Zc.(anonymous function).stopPropagation (ga.js:15)
    Gd (ga.js:31)
    Uc.(anonymous function).cb (ga.js:21)
    j (ga.js:14)
    E.F (ga.js:47)
    a.(anonymous function) (ga.js:14)
    E.O (ga.js:27)
    E.push (ga.js:25)
    a.(anonymous function) (ga.js:14)
    onclick ((index):21)
```

Comment: at face value I see nothing wrong with that code. There must be a conflict with it vs. something else on your page that FF somehow handles and the other browsers don't.

Comment: though.. and this could just be a posting typo.. you do have the GA script include stuff outside and after your body tag.. I have seen GA do some funky things when you don't put it in proper places.  But I'm guessing this is just a posting typo from you simplifying the code..

Comment: Yes that is correct, it is a posting typo because of me trying to simplify it, and staring at various version for 8 hours :-) The reply is appeciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting the initial ga function code first?

Comment: @DalmTo Yes I did. So turns out, that for some reason I have to set the domain name.

_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);

I have no idea why? Because i'm in my Dev environment and using localhost?

Comment: Also a handy tool called google-analytics-debugger that helps figure out "unobfuscated" error messages can be found here... [GA Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You figured out the answer to your problem on your own, but followed up with a question about why what you did worked:

> @DalmTo Yes I did. So turns out, that for some reason I have to set
>   the domain name. _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']); I have no idea
>   why? Because i'm in my Dev environment and using localhost?

Okay so you didn't originally mention that you were testing this locally. Had you mentioned that, I woulda been able to point this out! Just goes to show, leave no stone unturned when explaining a problem! Anyways...

GA won't send a request if it can't properly set its cookies. In order to properly set its cookies, it must know the domain. When you are working locally (localhost) there is no domain (e.g. `document.domain` yields and empty string).  So in order to get around this, GA allows you to set `_setDomainName` as 'none' so that it can know to work under that scenario.

As an alternative, you can add an entry to your OS hosts file (e.g. windows is `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to map your localhost ip (which is usually `127.0.0.1`) to a domain name, e.g.

`127.0.0.1   www.test.com`

And then I assume that you have a server setup locally e.g. apache or IIS or w/e, so make a virtualhost (apache) or host header (iis) for it, and you should now be able to go to e.g. `http://www.test.com/page.asp` instead of `http://localhost/page.asp` or w/e and then GA should be able to set cookies based on www.test.com without you having to use `_setDomainName`